# How to append two object using angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am having an object like this

```
   $scope.object1 = {  [{"customer_gid": 807,
    "customer_name": "APPLIANCES"}]}
```

so my data should be like this

```
 $scope.object2 = { [{"customer_gid": 807,
"customer_name": "APPLIANCES", type:[{"scheduletype_gid": 1, "scheduletype_code": "SCT001", "scheduletype_name": "BOOKING"}]}, }{"customer_gid": 798, "customer_name": "
AGENCIES PVT LTD"}, ]}]
```

how to append this two object using angularjs

Comment: Where is the other object to append?

Answer (score 1):

you can't put array directly in the object as : `{ [] }`

for doing that we should put `array` with param as: `{ myArray: [] }`

for appending another param to our object you can do this:

```
var object = { myArray: [{ somthing: 'test' }] }
object['another'] = { name: 'hello world' }
//result
//object  = { myArray: [{ somthing: 'test' }], another: { myArray: [{ somthing: 'test' }] } }
```

Comment: How does your answer match with what OP has asked?

Comment: lol, he changed the question over i was answer it :/ ... no choice i will update it

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```js
var target = {a: 1};
var source1 = {b: 2};
var newObj = Object.assign(target, source1);
console.log(newObj);
```